# AppSync VTL: Returning From Request Resolver Without Skipping Response Resolver

Tags: aws-appsync, vtl, aws-appsync-resolver

In AppSync VTL, I am attempting to generate log events in my response resolver vtl file, so I would prefer not to skip them.

Below is my request.vtl file.

```
#foreach($item in $ctx.source.get("songPlays"))
    $util.qr($item.put("globalContextStash", $ctx.source.get("globalContextStash")))
    $util.qr($item.put("language", $ctx.source.get("language")))
    $util.qr($item.put("songStatus", $ctx.source.get("songStatus")))
#end

## This works but I will skip my response.vtl. 
#return($ctx.source.songPlays)

## This did not work as I started getting an error. 
{
    "version" : "2018-05-29",
    "data": {               
        "songPlays": $util.toJson($ctx.source.songPlays)
    }       
}

## Received similar errors with this one. 
$util.toJson($salesPlays)
```

Answer (score 0):

Found that the object key of the returned valued should have been "payload"

```
{
    "version" : "2018-05-29",
    "payload": $util.toJson($songPlays)
}
```